# Counting records and grouping results by time of day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a bit used to SQL but I need your help on writing what I consider to be a complex expression. Here is the context. I have a table with records containing, to simplify, a record id (record_id), a call time (call_time) and a schedule time (dial_schedule_time).
I am trying to get the breakdown by time of the number of records. To give you an understanding of what I want to achieve, the result of my query should return something like this:

```
Now     |8      |9      |10     |11     |12     |13     |14     |15     |16     |17     |18     |19     |20     |
xxx     |xxx    |xxx    |xxx    |xxx    |xxx    |xxx    |xxx    |xxx    |xxx    |xxx    |xxx    |xxx    |xxx    |
```

where xxx represents the count of record_id grouped by time range during a day. To specify, "Now" represents the count of record_id for which call_time is null or dial_schedule_time value is inferior than the current date (not including the hour of the day, so for example if it is at the moment I run the query 25/01 @ 10am, "Now" would be the count of record_id where call_time is null or dial_schedule_time is < 25/01). The other ones (8, 9, 10...) represents the count of record_id where dial_sched_time is between today 8-9, today 9-10, today 10-11...
To make things a bit more difficult, dial_sched_time is a UNIX timestamp and the groupings need to be done taking into account the fact that this is New Zealand time (so for example 1474431093 is 21 sept 2016 04:11 GMT but is 21 sept 2016 16:11 NZT).

I don't really know where to start, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you :)

Sample data:

```
record_id   call_time   dial_sched_time
447495      1475887698  1485324000
447492      1479705246  1485320400
447488      NULL        1366005540
447485      NULL        1367193360
447482      NULL        1366701480
447478      NULL        1366705440
447476      NULL        1370502240
447471      NULL        1367816160
447469      NULL        1367564640
447468      1479705267  1485320400
447467      1476680578  1485320400
447466      NULL        1368767580
447531      1479169276  1479180158
447530      1479169360  1479180189
447529      NULL        1369105020
```

Comment: pivot is your friend . please share sample data and result expected I can try to write

Comment: Yes. Write a query to produce one row with each count you want, and then use PIVOT (or UNPIVOT) to take that and generate one row with a column for each result.

Comment: The thing is I am stuck with writing the query to get these time frames.

Answer (score 0):

To convert Unix timestamp to SQL Date format, try to use dateadd(s, @UnixTimestamp, '1970-01-01').
For instance dateadd(s, 1474431093, '1970-01-01') = 2016-09-21 04:11:33.000
Now, you can use group by over datepart(hh,dateadd(s, field_UnixTimestamp, '1970-01-01')) and COUNT() clause to obtain the number of call for each hour.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Ow... sorry...  and use PIVOT to "rotate" query results